# Fully qualified SQL Server query speed changes depending on current DB

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that looks essentially like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [TheDB].[dbo].[TheTable] [T1]
INNER JOIN [TheDB].[dbo].[TheTable] [T2] ON [T1].[Col] = [T2].[Col]
WHERE
  [T1].[ID] > [T2].[ID]
  AND [T1].[Type] = 'X'
  AND [T2].[Type] = 'X'
```

A fairly simple query designed to find some cases where we have some duplicate data.  (The `>` is used rather than `<>` just to keep from having the instances show up twice.)

We're explicitly naming the DB, schema, and table in each case.  Seems fine.

The odd thing is that if my SSMS is pointing to the DB in question, `TheDB`, the query never returns...it just spins and spins.  If, on the other hand, I point my SSMS to a different DB (changing it from, say, `TheDB` to `TheOtherDB`) or if I prefix my query with a line like `USE TheOtherDB`, then it returns instantly.

This is very repeatable, across restarts of SSMS, and for different users.

What's going on?  I'm guessing there's a wildly wrong optimization plan or something that is being used in some cases but not others...but the whole thing seems very strange...that pointing to the DB I'm actually using makes it slower.

To answer some of the questions/comments in the comments:

**What's the goal of the query?** To find 'duplicate' rows.  **Do I need to use `*`?**  No...and in the real query I'm not.  It's just part of the query anonymization.  I can change it to `[T1].[ID]` with the same result.

**Could be a bad cached plan...(any trivial modification to the query text should do, really)** I can change the query in various ways (like described above, returning just the `[T1].[ID]` for example and continue to get the same results.

**Perhaps the context databases have different compatibility levels...?** In this case, both DBs are set to have a compatibility level of "Sql Server 2019 (150)".

Comment: What is the *actual* goal of the above query? Do you *really* need *all* of the columns from the triangular join?

Comment: Could be a bad cached plan. As long as the DB and text match, you'll get the same plan. Try `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` (any trivial modification to the query text should do, really).

Comment: How many lines in the table? Is there an index on the column used in the join on the table in the local database? - and the other database?

Comment: Perhaps the context databases have different compatibility levels or different CE settings, which may result in different plans.

Comment: @Kendle The other DB that SSMS is pointing to when the query happens quickly does not have that table at all, so there's no chance it happens to be faster because I'm somehow looking at the wrong table and getting an index or data difference.

Comment: @DanGuzman Interesting.  I'll look into the compatibility level settings.  Thank you!  I'm not sure what a CE setting is...If it's for Compact Edition I can skip that...but if you meant something else just let me know.

Comment: CE = Cardinality Estimation. Influenced both by the compat level and (in newer versions) a separate setting that specifically governs it (`LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION`, along with other settings that affect plan generation).

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question. With the two execution plans to compare it should be clear what differences exist, e.g. an index in one database but not the other.

Comment: @HABO I don't have permissions for the execution plans in the DB.  That said, while I could in theory get someone who does have permissions to give me the plan for the one that completes, the other (more interesting) one never completes...it just spins, so no Actual Execution plan would be returned.  (though maybe the Estimated Execution plan might reveal something...?)

Comment: @Beska you can get the execution plan for a currently running query. I am actually unsure if it would be the estimated or actual execution plan. Perhaps someone else can chime in on that. I believe the the 'Show Live Execution Plan' option (when you right click a query in the 'Active Expensive Queries` dialogue) in SSMS Activity Monitor shows the actual execution plan.